# Import part of PDF based on coordinates

Tags: php, pdf, fpdi

I'm using FPDI to import a PDF.

```
<?php
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfReader;
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi/src/autoload.php');
$pdfpage2 = new Fpdi();
$pageCount = $pdfpage2->setSourceFile('dummy1.PDF');
$pageId = $pdfpage2->importPage(2);
$pdfpage2->addPage();
$pdfpage2->useImportedPage($pageId);
$pdfpage2->Output(F,'Part2.pdf');
```

This code works perfectly, but i'm wondering if I can import a part of page 2 based on coordinates.

like:

```
$pdfpage2->importPage(2, width, height, y, x);
```

Is there something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible without extending FPDI. You can use e.g. [this](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script78.php) script to create the clipping area. Just extend `setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi` instead of `FPDF` and the extension will work with FPDI, too.